# Dynamic Pivot Table by Month

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic, pivot, quotename

I'm trying to create a dynamic pivot table in SQL that will report based on month and year.  I did a bunch of research and was able to come up with the below query:

```
declare @dynamic nvarchar(max),
@column nvarchar(max);

set @column = N'';
select @column += N'' + datename(month,incurdate) +' '+ datename(year,incurdate) + ',' 
from (select distinct a.incurdate from artable a) as Transpose

select @column = substring(@column,0,len(@column))

set @dynamic = 'select * from
 (
select month, incurdate, dolamount
from artable join dolentry on month = period
) b
pivot(sum(dolamount) for incurdate in (' + @column + ')) as PivotTable'

execute sp_executesql @dynamic
```

I am able to print the @column variable successfully, but the problems happen when I try to set it in the @dynamic variable.  The error message is '*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '1990'.*'  1990 is the first year of the first pivoted column.  Any help or tips are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: you may enclose column names in square brackets. ex.`[1990]`

Comment: do a `PRINT @dynamic` and inspect the query, you will see the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the following code:

```
select @column += N'' + QUOTENAME(datename(month,incurdate) +' '+ datename(year,incurdate)) + ',' 
from (select distinct a.incurdate from artable a) as Transpose
```

in order to get output like this:

```
[col01], [col02], [col03], ... , [col04]
```

As you can see from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), the `PIVOT` syntax requires the pivoting columns to be wrapped in square brackets:

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```